How do I construct this natural cubic spline transformation matrix?
Say I have a natural cubic spline $f$ passing through $K = \{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_k,y_k)\}$ knot coordinates, and $\vec y = [y_1, y_2,...,y_n]^T$. Does there exist an $j$ x $k$ matrix $M$ such that $M\vec y = \vec{z}$, where $\vec z = [f(u_1), f(u_2),...,f(u_j)]^T$, a vector of the spline's values at $j$ arbitrary coordinates? Importantly, this $M$ cannot be a function of $\vec{y}$. I feel like it can be done given that a NCS is fully determined by its knot points. If so, how would I construct it?
I feel like it can be done with a Taylor expansion but I'm struggling to figure out exactly how.
